# Can I avoid some subtrees with a TreeWalker created with document.createTreeWalker?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am using a TreeWalker like this to traverse a HTML DOM:

```
var walker = document.createTreeWalker(root);
var node;
while (node = walker.nextNode()) { ... }
```

Can I avoid certain subtrees in some way? I guess it might be done with `walker.parentNode()`, but the documentation at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker) is not clear about this.

Comment: What conditions do you have in mind for avoiding subtrees?

Comment: @stackErr Classes and/or id.

Comment: Classes of the root node of the subtree? Or classes of some child/grandchild of the subtree?

Comment: @stackErr Classes of the root node of the subtree. Sorry for not beeing clear.

Comment: You might want to go through this: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Traversal-Range/traversal.html....Can't help much as I havent used this before

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Traversal-Range/traversal.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
getelementbyclass=function(node){
if (node.className=="blue") //filter out elements with this class attribute
return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT
else
return NodeFilter.FILTER_SKIP
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but does not the documentation say that the node filter parameter to createTreeWalker only is concerned with single nodes, not subtrees?

Comment: Check for Filter_Skip and if its true use the Sibling() method to go to the next subtree..

Comment: It works using node.nextSibling, at least in my example: http://jsfiddle.net/526kT/5/. (It is not using NodeFilter.) However the documentation at W3C is not clear about the traversel order so it might break.

Answer (score 1):

Use NodeFilter.FILTER_REJECT as the return value from your filter to bypass processing of subtrees. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeFilter for an example.

Comment: Looks like exactly what I was looking for when I asked this question. Thanks.